# What does Error: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe means?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to play a video from youtube in a dialogue alert. The video opens and play fine but once I entered the full screen and then leave, the cross button to close doesn't work and I have this error in my console. I'm new to flutter and I have no idea what it means or where it comes from.. Can someone help me solve it please?

Here is the full code of the home page as I don't know where it's coming from

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/anim_logo.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/phone_specific/animated_bottom_home_phone.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/web_specific/animated_bottom_home_web.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/current_date_display.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/languages.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/scrolling_image.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/sizing_functions.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/sizing_functions.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/sizing_functions.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/sizing_functions.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/state_and_logic.dart';
import 'package:geo_history_homepage/theme.dart';
import 'package:nil/nil.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';
import 'context_oval.dart';
import 'sizing_functions.dart';

class Home extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends ConsumerState<Home>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  // Map/List transition
  late bool phoneStyle;
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _spaceAnim;

  @override
  void initState() {
    phoneStyle = ref.read(phoneStyleProvider);
    //print(phoneStyle);
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: transitionPageTime),
    );
    initSpaceAnim(homePageId, homePageId, window.physicalSize.shortestSide,
        window.physicalSize.longestSide);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void initSpaceAnim(previous, next, total, totalPerp) {
    _spaceAnim = Tween<double>(
            begin: phoneStyle
                ? getSpaceHeightPhone(previous, total, totalPerp)
                : getSpaceLeft(previous, total),
            end: phoneStyle
                ? getSpaceHeightPhone(next, total, totalPerp)
                : getSpaceLeft(next, total))
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: const Interval(
        0.0,
        .8,
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    phoneStyle = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) <
        1.0;
    final totalWidth = getTotalWidth(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
    final totalHeight = getTotalHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
    final spaceForWorldTurning = getSpaceForWorldTurning(totalHeight);

    ref.listen(currentPage, (previous, next) {
      _animationController.reset();
      initSpaceAnim(
          previous,
          next,
          phoneStyle ? context.size?.height : context.size?.width,
          phoneStyle ? context.size?.width : context.size?.height);
      _animationController.forward();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Listened to controller $previous -> $next");
      }
    });

//title
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: greyBackground,
      body: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: ref.watch(listeningMode),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: totalHeight,
            child:
                Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <
                    Widget>[
              //Sky header part

              Expanded(
                  flex: phoneStyle ? ratioSkyPhone : ratioSky,
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    RepaintBoundary(
                        child: ScrollingImage(
                      //imagePath: 'images/etoiles_trsp2.png',
                      image: ref.watch(imagesProvider)["etoiles"]!,
                      speed: 600,
                      delay: 0.0,
                    )),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      width: totalWidth,

                      //height: heightSky,
                      color: Colors.transparent,

                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            child: Container(
                              margin: phoneStyle
                                  ? EdgeInsets.only(top: 35)
                                  : EdgeInsets.zero,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: textPadding / 2.0,
                                  horizontal: textPadding * 1.5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: titleBackground,
                                  border: phoneStyle
                                      ? Border.all(
                                          color: bordersColor,
                                          width: borderWidth)
                                      : const Border(
                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                              color: bordersColor,
                                              width: borderWidth),
                                          left: BorderSide(
                                              color: bordersColor,
                                              width: borderWidth),
                                          right: BorderSide(
                                              color: bordersColor,
                                              width: borderWidth))),
                              child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                child: Text(ref.watch(mainTitleTxt),
                                    //adding tertiary operator for title size
                                    style: phoneStyle
                                        ? styleTitle
                                        : styleBigTitle),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Expanded(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: phoneStyle ? 6 : 8,
                              child: LayoutBuilder(builder:
                                  (BuildContext context,
                                      BoxConstraints constraints) {
                                return Stack(children: [
                                  Align(
                                      // added width and height as parameter in the widget
                                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                      child: phoneStyle
                                          ? Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      horizontal: 15),
                                              child: ContextOval(
                                                  constraints.maxWidth *
                                                      (phoneStyle
                                                          ? ratioWidthOvalPhone
                                                          : ratioWidthOval),
                                                  constraints.maxHeight *
                                                      (phoneStyle
                                                          ? ratioHeightOvalPhone
                                                          : ratioHeightOval)),
                                            )
                                          : ContextOval(
                                              constraints.maxWidth *
                                                  ratioWidthOval,
                                              constraints.maxHeight *
                                                  ratioHeightOval)),
                                  Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                                          duration: const Duration(
                                              milliseconds: transitionPageTime),
                                          child: ref.watch(currentPage) ==
                                                  homePageId
                                              ? CurrentDateDisplay(
                                                  paddingAround: 0.0,
                                                  ratioHeight:
                                                      phoneStyle ? 0.65 : 0.4,
                                                  ratioSize: phoneStyle
                                                      ? 6 / 9
                                                      : 16 / 9,
                                                )
                                              : nil,
                                          transitionBuilder: (Widget child,
                                              Animation<double> animation) {
                                            final myAnimation =
                                                TweenSequence<double>([
                                              TweenSequenceItem(
                                                  tween: ConstantTween<double>(
                                                      0.0),
                                                  weight: 50),
                                              TweenSequenceItem(
                                                  tween: Tween<double>(
                                                          begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                                                      .chain(CurveTween(
                                                          curve: Curves
                                                              .easeInOut)),
                                                  weight: 50),
                                            ]).animate(animation);
                                            return FadeTransition(
                                                opacity: myAnimation,
                                                child: child);
                                          })),
                                  Positioned(
                                      // "faites défiler txt phone style + 20 top"
                                      left: phoneStyle
                                          ? 0.10 * constraints.maxWidth
                                          : 0.15 * constraints.maxWidth,
                                      top: phoneStyle
                                          ? 0.35 * constraints.maxHeight
                                          : 0.45 * constraints.maxHeight -
                                              0.2 * constraints.maxHeight,
                                      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                                          duration: const Duration(
                                              milliseconds: transitionPageTime),
                                          child: ref.watch(currentPage) ==
                                                  homePageId
                                              ? SizedBox(
                                                  height: 0.2 *
                                                      constraints.maxHeight,
                                                  child: FittedBox(
                                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                                      child: Text(
                                                          ref.watch(dragMeTxt),
                                                          style: phoneStyle
                                                              ? styleContent
                                                              : styleSubHeader)))
                                              : nil,
                                          transitionBuilder: (Widget child,
                                              Animation<double> animation) {
                                            final myAnimation =
                                                TweenSequence<double>([
                                              TweenSequenceItem(
                                                  tween: ConstantTween<double>(
                                                      0.0),
                                                  weight: 50),
                                              TweenSequenceItem(
                                                  tween: Tween<double>(
                                                          begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                                                      .chain(CurveTween(
                                                          curve: Curves
                                                              .easeInOut)),
                                                  weight: 50),
                                            ]).animate(animation);
                                            return FadeTransition(
                                                opacity: myAnimation,
                                                child: child);
                                          }))
                                ]);
                              })),
                          const Expanded(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      //mapmonde
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                          width: phoneStyle
                              ? spaceForWorldTurning / 2
                              : spaceForWorldTurning,
                          height: phoneStyle
                              ? spaceForWorldTurning / 2
                              : spaceForWorldTurning,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          //EdgeInsets.all(spaceForWorldTurning * 0.0),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Center(
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      ref.read(currentPage.notifier).state =
                                          homePageId;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: const LogoAnim()))),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Container(
                          width: phoneStyle ? 90 : 150,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(textPadding),
                          child: FittedBox(
                            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton2(
                                items: Language.supportedLanguagesList()
                                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (lang) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                        value: lang.shortcut,
                                        // children display only when dropeddown?
                                        child: phoneStyle
                                            ? Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                lang.flag,
                                                style: styleSubHeader,
                                              ))
                                            : Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceBetween,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                              .symmetric(
                                                          horizontal: 5.0),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        lang.flag,
                                                        style: styleSubHeader,
                                                      )),
                                                  FittedBox(
                                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                                      child: Text(lang.name,
                                                          style: styleTitle))
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                    .toList(),
                                //display only the map monde? or the map and the flag?
                                value: ref.watch(currentLanguage),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    ref.read(currentLanguage.notifier).state =
                                        value as String;
                                  });
                                },
                                iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.language),
                                buttonHeight: 40,
                                buttonWidth: phoneStyle ? 60 : 150,
                                itemHeight: 40,
                                dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                  color: purpleList,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                    )
                  ])),
              Container(
                color: bordersColor,
                width: totalWidth,
                height: borderWidth,
              ),
              //Map part
              Expanded(
                  flex: phoneStyle ? ratioMapPhone : ratioMap,
                  child: phoneStyle
                      ? AnimatedBottomHomePhoneWidget(
                          progress: _animationController,
                          spaceAnimTween: _spaceAnim,
                          ref: ref,
                          totalHeight: totalHeight)
                      : AnimatedBottomHomeWidget(
                          progress: _animationController,
                          spaceAnimTween: _spaceAnim,
                          ref: ref,
                          totalWidth: totalWidth))
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCloseIcon extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyCloseIcon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Icon(ref.watch(onHover) ? Icons.clear_outlined : Icons.clear_sharp,
        color:
            ref.watch(onHover) ? Colors.black : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3));
  }
}

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Stack(children: [
      Text(ref
          .watch(videoListProvider.notifier)
          .get(ref.watch(currentId))
          .title),
      Positioned(
          right: 0.0,
          top: 0.0,
          child: InkResponse(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            radius: 0,
            onHover: (e) {
              ref.read(onHover.notifier).update((state) => !state);
            },
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            child: const MyCloseIcon(),
          ))
    ]),
    content: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75 * 300 / 500,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
//using a YoutubePlayerScaffold when full screen support is required
        child: YoutubePlayer(
          controller: YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
              params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
                  showFullscreenButton: true, showControls: true),
              videoId: YoutubePlayerController.convertUrlToId(ref
                      .watch(videoListProvider.notifier)
                      .get(ref.watch(currentId))
                      .link)
                  .toString()),
          aspectRatio: 300 / 500,
          // builder: (context, player) {
          //   return player;
          // },
        )),
    /*actions: [
      okButton,
    ],*/
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    //barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

And here is what my console is showing. Every time I move my mouse a new error appears saying just that the assertion failed..

[image: Debug console output]